# anchorlink in navigation with slide-function jumps too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

The navigationlink "Leistungen" (marked black in below image) is linking to an anchor where you can find an carousel-slider. The submenu is doing the same + firing the function to slide to the relating carousel-slide.

```
<a href="https://bm-translations.de/#leistungen" onclick="document.getElementById('carousel-selector-1').click()">Beglaubigungen</a>
```

[image]

But out of some reason if you load the following site and try it, its jumping too far (following image): https://bm-translations.de/

[image]

The strange thing is, if you then click a 2nd time the same navigation link, it is jumping to the right anchor.

Why is this happening and how to solve this?

Comment: It's not scrolling too far. Your header simply covers part of your carousel.

Comment: have a look, I updated my question and attached an image where it is jumping on my site (chrome).

Comment: Weird. Is the ID 'carousel-selector-1' set only once?

Comment: I gave an answer, but I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for, after rereading your question I don't think I've been able to replicate your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a Solution:

```
<a onclick="document.getElementById(&quot;carousel-selector-1&quot;).click();location=&quot;https://bm-translations.de/#leistungen&quot;">Beglaubigungen</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your page, after clicking that menu link, it scrolls down to where that section is in the document.

It's scrolling down to a block element (I assume some JS script is smooth scrolling it to the ID):

```
<div class="row" id="leistungen"></div>
```

In your H2 element directly inside of that div, you have your heading with some padding on top:

```
<h2 style="text-align:center;font-size:24px;padding-top:30px">Leistungen Ihres Übersetzungsbüros</h2>
```

If you added that padding yourself, go ahead and increase that to 90px (or whatever amount you want).

Or else just add this to the bottom of your css file:

```
#leistungen > h2 { padding-top: 90px; }
```

The only alternative is to edit the JS that's creating the smooth scrolling feature.

EDIT: I'd even recommend streamlining your H2 padding in css, not on the page... each of your H2's have their own unique padding-top.

---

Before: 
[image: site before]

After:

[image: site after]

Comment: yap, thats not what I am aiming, but thanks for trying to help! Maybe you can replicate the issue after refreshing page (strg+f5)? Maybe its because of cashing.

Comment: @KrystianManthey what browser are you using? can you try opening the page up in a new browser and tell me if you still have the same issue?

Comment: its in every browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox - tested with 2 computers). When I click for example "Beglaubigungen" in the dropdown of "Leistungen" I am heading like the 2nd image in my question. But when I then again click "Beglaubigungen" its jumping correctly